# rename file with add length (in bytes) power shell

Tags: powershell-2.0, rename, maxlength, get-childitem

i have a problem : in files name i have to write their lengths

for example  qwerty.tmp → qwerty_12039.tmp ! please help

use:

get-childitem c:\Folder |  rename-item -NewName {$_.name -replace ".tmp", $_length ".tmp"}

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You left '.' there. Also: I would use BaseName instead:

```
ls C:\folder | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName + $_.Length + '.tmp' }
```